# How to use ``OUTPUT`` in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've always used Sublime Text 3 for Python Coding, in which `Build Systems` were the only way of running a file.

Now I'm starting C++ programming, and I'm using `VSCode`.  The problem I have is that, in that dock where:

`PROBLEMS` , `OUTPUT` , `DEBUG CONSOLE` , `TERMINAL`

[image]

The only thing I've had trouble with, is `OUTPUT` window, because nothing ever appears, so if I wanna run either Python or C++ code, it won't show anything to let me know what output would the program give.  And if I just try to run it (pressing f5) it, it will open terminal and run it from it.

I saw something called `Tasks` but I don't know how they work, and they seem to be like `Build Systems` from Sublime Text 3.

**I want to use `OUTPUT` window, how can I get it working?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to run code in the output section of visual studio code you can use the extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

just install, then press `CTRL + ALT + N` to run the file (supports c++ & python)

Comment: +1 but it's worth noting, that ***you*** aren't using the Output Window here, an extension is, as mentioned in my answer. Just want that to be clear for any new people learning vscode. This could be a bad thing if the extension ever stops receiving support or fails to work

Answer (score 3):

> I want to use OUTPUT window, how can I get it working?

As it stands now, you can not use the Output Window as a way to log code, that is reserved for native logs like Window, Main, Shared or Extensions to log their output using channels. There is a good candidate called the Debug Console.

You can log to the Debug Console using a `launch.json` configurable:

First, create a [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) for your program.

Then add the following properties, in addition to whatever you need to get your program going:

`internalConsoleOptions`

> Controls when the internal debug console should open

`redirectOutput`

Both of these used in tandem will open the 'Debug Console' instead of terminal and just provide the necessary output; though it still sends to terminal should you still want it:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "redirectOutput": true
    }
]
```

[image: 1]

---

For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) they have an extensive tutorial on how to debug and run: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp (in addition to setting up `launch.json` and `tasks.json` files respectively https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_build-helloworldcpp)

Answer (score 0):

Installation
Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter.

```
ext install formulahendry.code-runner
```